# LESS variables from differrent source

Tags: less

I have a set of .less files

these are imported in theme.less likes this

```
    @import "a.less";
    @import "b.less";
    @import "c.less";
```

and compiles to theme.css

I got 2 less files which defines same variables with different values.

```
    vars_blue.less
    vars_green.less
```

this is for theming. a.less,b.less & c.less refer these variables.
If I import vars_blue.less in above 3 less files, i will get blue theme.

I am trying to create a dynamic theme but avoiding include of variables in above 3 files, instead in theme.less

```
    @import "vars_blue.less";
    @import "a.less";
    @import "b.less";
    @import "c.less";
```

since variables are used in 3 child .less files above is not supported.
its expecting to import in each .less file where its used.

How to create 2 theme.less like

```
    theme_blue.less

    @import "vars_blue.less";
    @import "a.less";
    @import "b.less";
    @import "c.less";
```

and

```
    theme_green.less

    @import "vars_green.less";
    @import "a.less";
    @import "b.less";
    @import "c.less";
```

Comment: what are you avoiding importing in each file ? is it because you'll need to modify it in each file when changing theme or because the compiled file will be too big (3 times the same import) ?

Comment: I want to theme by changing variables import in theme file, not in each child .less Files

Comment: *since variables are used in 3 child .less files above is not supported* - it *is* supported actually. Variables defined in an imported file are visible in *all other* imported files *regardless* of where any of this is imported. So the code in your "I'm trying" section" is perfectly correct (Have you actually ever tried it?).

Comment: I tried. Build failing with error as variables undefined

Comment: *I tried. Build failing with error as variables undefined* - it should not. Make sure you compile only your main file (the one where everything is imported) and not "all files in the dir" or a sort of (it's a common mistake).

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know how to use `less` so my answer could be very bad.

In these kind of case how about making it this way :

you create a `theme_vars.less` containing only :

```
@import "vars_green.less";
```

or

```
@import "vars_blue.less";
```

then in `a.less`, `b.less` and `c.less` your start by :

```
@import "theme_vars.less";
```

this way when you need to change theme, only `theme_vars.less` need to be modified

(kinda like an [abstract factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern))